# Wordpress register data in custom table within plugin admin dashboard page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to write a plugin using the Boilerplate template. I am almost done. However I need to implement the possibility of saving some data in a custom table that is created at the plugin activation.

Following the Boilerplate template, I created in
`my_plugin/admin/class-myplugin_admin.php` a dashboard page and a setting submenu page, following the instructions given. Settings manage some options that are saved in wp_options and they do work.

In the folder `my_plugin/admin/partials` I have two files

`sighting-form-admin-settings-display.php` -> displays the Settings Options page

`sighting-form-admin-display.php` -> shows the shortcode to copy

In `sighting-form-admin-display.php` I want also to add the possibility to customize data in the custom table created at the activation (which is empty).

My code is this

```
    <div class="wrap">
                <div id="icon-themes" class="icon32"></div>  
                <h2>Sighting Form Tethys Use</h2>  
                <p>In order to use the form add the following shortcode to your page</p>
                <p>[sight-form-shortcode]</p>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap">
    <h3>Add Species</h3>
    <form id="#add-species" method="post" action="">
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'submit_species_nonce' ); ?>
        <label for="species_name">Species Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="species_name" name="species_name">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_species" value="Add Species">
    </form>
    <h3>List species already added</h3>
    <table>
        
    <?php global $wpdb;
                $query_species = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT species_name FROM idp_sigh_form_species", ARRAY_A); 
            foreach($query_species as $row_species) {
                $species = stripslashes($row_species['species_name']);?>
                <tr><td>Species name: <?php echo $species;?></td></tr><?php
            }
            ?>
    </table>
  </div>
    <?php
    function insert_species_data($species_name) {
    global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'sigh_form_species';
        $result= $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            array(
                'species_name' => $species_name
            )
        );
        if ($result === false) {
            error_log("Failed to insert species data into the database: " . $wpdb->last_error);
        }
    
    }
add_action('admin_init', 'handle_species_form_submission');
function handle_species_form_submission() {
global $wpdb;

    if (isset($_POST['submit_species'])) {
        // Verify nonce
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'submit_species_nonce' ) ) {
            // Nonce verification failed; handle this case
            error_log('Nonce verification failed.');
            return;
        }
        // Retrieve the submitted species name
        $species_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['species_name']);    
        // Insert species data into the custom table
        insert_species_data($species_name);
        // Debugging: Output any database errors
        $wpdb_errors = $wpdb->last_error;
        if ($wpdb_errors) {
            error_log('Database error: '. $wpdb_errors);
        }
        // Redirect back to the settings page after submission
        wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=sighting-form-tethys'));
        exit();
    }
}
```

I don't see any error, but nothing is saved in the table. However if I insert some data manually in the custom table, data are shown in the table under "List species already added".

What am I doing wrong?